# How to Monitor connection leak using weblogic

Tags: weblogic

I need to monitor connection leak from weblogic , I google and found , need to enable profile connection leak ( Domain > Services > JDBC > Data Sources > DS Name > Connection Pool > Advanced) but I am unable to find the option in weblogic. I found the column leaked connection count under Monitoring->JDBC . Want to know how to use it also

Answer (score 1):

Probably you already visit Oracle documentation, JIC:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JDBCA/monitor.htm#JDBCA236

An interesting post about it (with an example) can be found at:
http://blog.sysco.no/db/locking/jdbc-leak/

More than monitoring, many times is easier to set up "Inactive Connection Timeout" to 5 minutes (or whatever time that you think is long enough for a leak).

Then WLS will throw a stacktrace of the leaked connection, which will you a hint which thread (connection) is STUCK.